cannot find entry symbol _start when trying to link c main with assembly function
Can read assembly but trying to learn to write small functions in it, but I can't seem to link a main written in C that calls an extern function written with gas. The target is linux x64.
Here is main.c:
#include <stdio.h>

extern int somefunc();

int main() {
  int x = somefunc();
  printf("returned %d\n", x);
  return 0;
}

here is sf.s:
.global somefunc

.data
.text

somefunc:
  movl $123, %eax
  ret

Here are the compilation commands:
> gcc -c -fno-pie main.c -o main.o
> as sf.s -o sf.o
> ld -lc main.o sf.o -o m
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401020


You need the C compiler crt0.o et. al. files. Link using gcc instead of ld. And, put the -lc at the end. gcc main.o sf.o -o m -lc

@CraigEstey I don't see it on my system. When linked with gcc it works fine, but where does it get it from? Where would I get it? I'd like to try to do the full compile and link chain by hand ffor once.

@JasonNordwick gcc knows where it is. It is in the specs file.

@gulpr Thank you. It appears the spec files are built into gcc and not in the file system. Also crt0 is now called something else. There are many other crt* files in the x86 directory (crtbeigin, crtend, etc...). Thank you.

You may have your own specs files too. Many crt files-as startup is complex thing

@gulpr if you want to post these as an as an answer I'll accept it.

Those fings in gcc are usually defined in specfiles. You can see the default file by using -dumpspecs command line option.
